# How do I show that $\mu$ is a measure?

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $S$ be a semiring, and let $\mu: S \to [0,\infty]$ be a set function such that $\mu(A) < \infty$ for some $A \in S$. If $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive, then show that $\mu$ is a measure.

What exactly do I need to show that $\mu$ is a measure?

> I know that a set function $\mu:S \to [0, \infty]$ is a measure if:
>
> - $\mu(\emptyset)=0$
> - $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive

I also have the following characterisation of a measure on a semiring:

> $\mu:S\to [0,\infty]$ is a measure on $S$ if and only if:
>
> - $\mu(\emptyset)=0$
> - If $A \in S$ and $_1, \dots, A_n \in S$ satisfy $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i \subseteq A$ and $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$ when $i \neq j$, then $\sum_{i=1}^n \mu(a_i) \le \mu(A)$ holds.
> - $\mu$ is $\sigma$-subadditive.

I seem to get confused which one of these I need to try and use in order to show that $\mu$ is a measure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have that $\mu(\emptyset)=0$ yet.

However to see this is not that hard. Since $A=A\cup\emptyset$ and $A$ and the empty set are disjoint, just use $\sigma$ additivity to get that $\mu(A)=\mu(A)+\mu(\emptyset)$ which since $\mu(A)<\infty$ implies that $\mu(\emptyset)=0$.